# Java spring boot webservices and html

Tags: java, html, spring

I made a Post method in `java restful services`. When from front end user clicked on button for the first time there will be an error page showing the error message given below and I am getting this error only for the first time. Second time when user click it, it's working fine.

Whitelabel Error Page

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Jan 27 03:51:51 EST 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not
>   supported

This is my controller file:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/classify",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody    
List<List<HashMap<Object,Object>>> doClassify1( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse resp)  {

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Start of Classify");
        prop = new Properties() ;
        input = StwTagController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        prop.load(input) ;

        String rdurl  = prop.getProperty("plmclassify") ;
        String appId = request.getParameter("appId");

        String appType = request.getParameter("appType");
        String[] objectData =  request.getParameterValues("objectData");        
        parentId = request.getParameter("parentObjectId");
        String userId = request.getHeader("sm_ssoid");
        obj = stwTagService.doClassify(appId,appType,objectData,parentId,userId );      

        resp.sendRedirect(rdurl+parentId);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Show your client code

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from your error message :

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Your html is connecting to your webservice by using a HTTP GET method instead of a POST method wanted by your request mapping :

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/classify",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: i mentioned method as post in my html file.